# Deploying Qt application on OSX issue finding GStreamer plugins

Tags: c++, macos, qt, deployment, gstreamer

I am trying to deploy an application on OSX 10.8.5 which builds and runs on an OSX system but I am having runtime issues when the application is started due to it not location a GStreamer Plugin (in this case osxvideosink).

I did the following steps to make the .app bundle.

1. Compiled the application in QtCreator release mode.
2. Ran macdeployqt on the resulting .app file
3. Added in additional libraries e.g. boost and gstreamer.
4. Used macdependency to find which paths were wrong, changed them to the right ones. All of the dependencys are found within the .app bundle and no errors are reported.
5. Ran the software on the machine with the libraries install and it works.
6. Made a .dmg file and moved it onto another machine. Copied out the .app.
7. Ran it and it work for a few seconds until the required gstreamer plugin is loaded when it crashes out as it cannot find that plugin.

The way I see it, it could be caused by two issues. 1. osxvideosink does not work on that machine, which would be odd as it works on machines with exactly the same operation system. Or the libosxvideosink.dylib file is not found by the linker at run time.

I'm pretty new to macs so any help / ideas would be appreciated.